# Как изменить директорию сохранения сайтов в open server?

Tags: localhost

Скачал open server, все работает, но хотелось бы изменить директорию, откуда сервер запускает сайты. Может кто нибудь знает, где можно это настроить?

Comment: Ты имеешь ввиду этот программный комплекс https://ospanel.io/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тоже интересовался, но нужного ответа в этой теме не увидел. Может кому надо будет, то: в настройках во вкладке "Сервер" меняем корневую папку доменов на нужную.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в настройки, затем во вкладку "Домены". В выпадающем списке выберите пункт "Ручное управление". Далее вводим имя домена, выбираем папку с проектом, нажимаем кнопку "Добавить". Потребуется перезапуск сервера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Источник](https://php-start.com/blog/open-server-domains-php-start-project)

Comment: А возможно ли сохранят сайты не в папке ../OpenServer/domains, а в другом месте?

Comment: А на втором скрине что показано?..

Comment: Я уже сам разобрался спасибо

Comment: Если мой ответ вам помог - отметьте его как правильный. Или дайте свой, правильный ответ.

Comment: А на втором скрине показано, что файл сохраняется в папке /OpenServer/domains, а не в другом месте.

Comment: @ДмитрийИсаенко А разве другое место выбрано? \ в начале пути говорит о том, что он относителен родительского каталога.